# In Android, I am not able to find few symbols inside my .so file?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, .so

I generate a .so file during my build and add it in the right place inside 'jnilibs' folder but I am facing an error stating "Cannot find the native function implementation with Unsatisfied Link Error"

```
// This is my .kt file

import abc.def.xyz

class MainActivity : Activity () {

public external fun MyNativeFunction() : Boolean

    override
    fun onCreate (pSavedInstance : Bundle?) 
    {
        super.onCreate (pSavedInstance)
    
        // Calling my Native function
    
        val check = MyNativeFunction ()
    }
}


// This is my .cpp file

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_abc_def_xyz_MainActivity_MyNativeFunction () noexcept

{

     // .... some code written here

    return true;
}
```

It's not able to find the function's implementation 'MyNativefunction'. Even the signature is correct but couldn't find where I am going wrong.

When I tried to extract the symbols from my generated .so file I was not able to see the this function inside the .so file. Can somebody tell me where I am going wrong?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You left out the build system that creates the shared library from your cpp file, everything else looks fine.

Comment: I have multiple.cpp files of which we create multiple .a libraries and then we link it to a single .so file

When I dumped the .a file I am able to see my native function symbol and it's present inside that 

But when I dump the .so file I am not able to see my native function inside that file 

Command used: "nm -gDC yourlibname.so" 

During linking libraries we use  "target-link-library" of CMake

Comment: Your C++ function is missing the two arguments (`JNIEnv*, jobject`). Is that what your actual code looks like?

Comment: Voting to close as cannot reproduce, since there's no [mre] or information to go on.